# Delegate is nil when i pass as self with function parameter in swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

This is user class

```
import UIKit

class UserInfoHandler: NSObject,NetworkOperationDelegate {

var operationDelegate:NetworkOperationDelegate?

override init() {
    super.init()
}


func fetchUser(userId id:NSString) {

    //self.block = block
    let appDelegate = AppDelegate.sharedDelegate()

    let userId = id as String
    let token = appDelegate.token as! String

    let userHanlder = UserHandler()
    userHanlder.fetchUser(userId: userId, token: token, delegate: self)

}
// Network operation delegate
func didCompleteOperation(operation: NetworkOperation) {

    print(operation)
}

}
```

My Questions are:

```
userHanlder.fetchUser(userId: userId, token: token, **delegate: self**)
```

1. `Delegate` is nil in the `NetworkOperation` class. Why?
2. When I create instance of `NewtworkOperationDelegate`, and pass it to function it is not nil. How?

please help me, i have spent more than one week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the code how you are assigning delegate in NetworkOperation class

Comment: self.delegate = operationDelegate

Comment: No, this is not helpful can you post the whole class both NetworkOperation and UserHandler

Comment: let operation = NetworkOperation(requestObject: self)
        operation.delegate = operationDelegate
        NetworkManager.sharedManager.operationQueue.addOperation(operation)

Comment: your code flow and classes are hard for me to understand, have a look here to understand how delegates work : http://stephenradford.me/creating-a-delegate-in-swift/